# A GMAT exam question on algebra-precalculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus

in the annual performance appraisal all employees were placed in three categories-average, good and excellent. To execute the appraisal plan more effectively, a software called "Appraise well" is being used. But somehow the computer got infected and data was lost. While trying to recover the data, only the following data was recovered

```
    Average   Good   Excellent   Total
```

Male                          12
Female                                36
Total              33

Male excellent 12
Female total 36
total good 33

Data given

An employee can be placed in only one category
Half the employees are either excellent or good
40% of the employees are females
One third of the males were average

It was easy to find the total number of people

$40/100*x=36$
$x=90$
Male=54

I want to know how the number of female in excellent category will be zero?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. In particular, we have

Average: 18 males, 27 females

Good: 24 males, 9 females

Excellent: 12 males, 0 female

Comment: How number of females in excellent category is zero? @MathLover

Comment: Hey @MathLover, can you please tell me how number of females in excellent category is zero?

Comment: You mentioned, "Half the employees are either excellent or good." Which means $45$ employees are either excellent or good. We know that the total number of good employees is $33$, and we have $12$ males in the excellent category. Since $33+12=45$, no female employee can be in the excellent category.